# Error says 'aw' might not be initialised in this constructor in cpp

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
Aww::Aww()
{
  aw = NULL;
}

Aww::~Aww()
{
  if(aw)
  {
    delete aw;
    aw = 0;
  }
}
```

I am not getting what is going wrong.I am initailizing aw to `NULL` in constructor and I am deleting it in destructor and again initializing it to 0 but it just says that it might not be initialised in constructor,codeis done in cpp.
Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Can you add a declaration of `aw`, please?

Comment: There is no syntax error in this code (if you have aw pointer in your Aww class).

Comment: You don't need to check if aw is null, just call delete (or better yet use a smart pointer since you probably now have a default copy constructor that doesn't do what you want it to)

Comment: "I am initailizing aw to NULL" - you're *assigning* NULL to `aw`. Until that assignment `aw` is uninitialized. See tojanfoe's answer for member initialization syntax. That may be what the pedantic warnings your using are warning about. Out of curiosity, what is issuing that warning? Is it the compiler or some static analysis tool? Toolchain info and warning levels for said-same would be helpful to clarify your question.

Comment: Also remember to define the copy constructor. The compiler-generated one almost certainly *won't* do what you want. But better make `aw` a `std::unique_ptr` so you don't have to have your own destructor.

Comment: I am using Visual studio ,declaring aw same way as stated. i think this would work@trojanfoe ans.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it like this:

```
Aww::Aww() :
    aw(NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: aw(NULL)means assigning aw toNULL?

Comment: No, it's _initializing_. You _assign_ a new value to an existing variable, but _initializing_ is about the _initial_ value.

Comment: and what if i want to asssign it 0 can i do it like aw->0 ?